# Incorrect results from READ UNCOMMITTED transaction level beyond expected behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, isolation-level

**Preface:** I'm looking to move towards using snapshot isolation in the future, but for now, I'd like to understand what's going on with my query.

I understand that dirty reads (READ UNCOMMITTED, NOLOCK) don't just ignore locks, but that they can also be subject to inconsistent results due to things like page splits occurring *during* a dirty read.  However, I'm seeing the same incorrect results returned every single time which I can't associate with any of the consistency pitfalls I've read about.

I have a large table called RUN which has millions of rows in it.  We never UPDATE rows, we only INSERT.  I have one query that's trying to retrieve data coming in within the last few days.  This query is running with READ UNCOMMITTED, and it always returns the same incorrect results.

### Here's an example of my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE run
{
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , someTableID INT NOT NULL
    , locationID INT NOT NULL
    , statusID INT NOT NULL
    , value INT NULL
    , date_time DATETIME NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT runs_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id asc) 
}

-- My queries automatically use this index, and I only get correct results when READ COMMITTED
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX run_ix ON run ( someTableID, locationID, date_time) INCLUDE (statusID)
-- When I force my queries to use this index, I get correct results even when READ UNCOMMITTED
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX run_uk ON run ( date_time, locationID, statusID, someTableID, id) INCLUDE (value)
```

### Here's the problem queries:

I expect 60 results to come back, with dates between 2013-05-31 to 2013-06-05:

```
CREATE VIEW testView AS 
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *, RANK() over (PARTITION BY someTableID, locationID ORDER BY date_time ASC) rnk
        FROM run 
        WHERE statusID = 1 AND date_time BETWEEN '2013-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-08 00:00:00'
    ) a WHERE rnk = 1



SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
GO
-- Always returns 15
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testView
GO

-- Always returns 15, 2013-06-05, 2013-06-05
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time) FROM testView
GO

-- Always returns 60 rows
SELECT * FROM testView
GO
```

Notice that selecting all the results actually returns all the rows, where as queries with aggregates return incorrect results.

I was able to determine that switching to READ COMMITTED returned the correct results.  Also, I tried rewriting the query in a way that caused it to use a different index, and that gave me the correct results as well (I don't have an example of this here).

### Here are working queries:

```
-- Always returns 60
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testView WITH (INDEX(

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO

-- Always returns 60
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testView
GO

-- Always returns 60, 2013-05-31 , 2013-06-05
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time) FROM testView
GO

-- Always returns 60 rows
SELECT * FROM testView
GO
```

The index in question had about 6% fragmentation.  I'm not sure if this is representative of its normal fragmentation level, as we have a weekly job that rebuilds indexes over 15% or so.  REORGANIZEing the index used by the query would temporarily cause the query to return the correct result even in a dirty read, but after a minute or two I'd go back to getting incorrect results.

I noticed that immediately after reorganizing the index, its fragmentation was ~0.68% and would creep closer to 0.8% after a few minutes, probably from new data coming in.  I'm not sure if the fragmentation is responsible for the incorrect results or not, but It's all I've got to go on right now.

We only have around 500 inserts an hour.  There's no way page splits are occurring every single time I run the query, resulting in incorrect data, and even if there were, it wouldn't explain to me why I always get the same results back.

Note: we have hundreds of other dirty read queries, and have for years.  I can't say this is the first and only time there's ever been a problem, bu it's the first time we've ever identified this issue.

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be going on?  Could it be related to the fragmentation level of the index?

### Update:

I think the problem has something to do with IAM's and the fact that my queries are performing an Allocation Order Scan.

The value column isn't contained in an index.  Running this query causes the index scan to be set to ORDERED: TRUE, and I get the proper results

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
GO
SELECT value FROM testView
```

The date_time column is contained in an index.  Running this query causes the index scan to be set to ORDERED: FALSE, and I get the wrong results

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
GO
SELECT date_time FROM testView
```

Comment: What happens if you force no parallelism `WITH (MAXDOP 1)`?

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow.  Any reason why you think that could be a problem?

Comment: It's just a hunch--may not be anything. It's good to get rid of parallelism when trying to understand SQL Server strange behavior, because it *has* caused problems in the past.

Comment: I don't recall seeing any parallel operations occurring in the query plan, but I'll try it anyway.  I've seen parallelism cause performance problems, but nothing like this.

Comment: With only 60 rows I'm probably barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: Have you checked the database for corruption?

Comment: I'm going to try that soon.  I figured since I got the correct behavior when I used read committed - and because the DBA's have various health monitors in place - that this was unlikely.

Comment: DBCC CHECKTABLE doesn't report any errors.  I'll see if the DBAs can perform a CHECKDB on off hours, but I don't think there's a problem.

Comment: Reason for the question is that my thought was an IAM ordered scan too but your query doesn't seem to be using any non deterministic constructs so the results should be the same except if somehow one of the scan methods was missing data.

Comment: Well, removing the RANK() from the query also produces the correct results.  The example query I have above is a little simpler than the real query, which is a nested set of views.  We're running build 9.00.5069.00, and I don't see any bug fixes that look like they could be related.

Comment: Well maybe the actual query does contain some non deterministic element then. e.g. filtering on `ROW_NUMBER` would be non deterministic in the event of ties.